# Epsilon-delta proof of the continuity of a function

Tags: calculus, limits

I understand (mostly) the solution to this problem however I'm having difficulty understanding how they've made the leap from $0<x<2$  to  $0<|x||x+1|<6$ so if anyone could explain it to me I'd really appreciate it. Thanks

**Question**:

> Give an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof of the continuity of the function $f(x)=x^3-x$ at $x=1$.

**Answer**:

Note $f(1)=0.$ So given ϵ>0 want δ>0 s.t.
$|x-1|<δ => |x^3-x-0|<ϵ.$

I.e.

$ |x(x^2-1)|<ϵ$

$|x||x+1||x-1|<ϵ$

Choose $\delta<1$ =>

$ 0<x<2 $. 
So, $0<|x||x+1|<6$.

So for $\delta< \min \{1,\frac\epsilon6\}$ we have $|f(x)-f(1)|<6(\epsilon/6)=\epsilon$.

Comment: If $|x|<2$, then $|x+1| < 3$. So $|x||x+1| < 2 \cdot 3 = 6$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $0<x<2\Longrightarrow 0<|x|<2 \text{ and } 1<|x+1|<3$.
 
Now use that if $0\leq a<b$ and $0\leq c<d$ then $ ac<bd$.

Answer (score 0):

when 
0< x < 2
there be

x(x+1)=x^2+x=(x+1/2)^2-1/4

max when x=2

and 
x(x+1)=6

min when x=0

and x(x+1)=0

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.StackExchange. Please note that our forum supports [pretty mathematics](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) via MathJAX and it'd be great if you can take advantage of that feature.

Comment: thankyou i would learn how to use the MathJAX